# Confused about the meaning

Tags: meaning

Bit confused about the meaning of this extract.

Information systems deliver value.

Information systems support business processes to deliver value.

An information system is a set of interwoven components that deliver meaningful information to support processes that strategically manage, coordinate and control an organisation to deliver value

Is it saying that information systems support business processes in order to deliver value, or is it saying that information systems helps business processes deliver value?

Thank you

Comment: Could you clarify your question by [editing](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/441461/edit) and adding `>` before the sentences you are quoting, please? Which of these sentences are the actual quote and which are your commentary?

Comment: This is first and foremost a more detailed duplicate of a semantically indentical Question from not long ago.

Comment: If you have a single “extract” where  “Information systems deliver… ” and “… support business processes to deliver value” please do cite it.

Either way, how d’you think there’s anything to be explained, please?

What difference do you see between “supporting business processes… to deliver value” and “helping business processes deliver value”, please?

Is the Question whether “supporting” and “helping” mean anything different, or is it something else, please?